# How to mock a jdbctemplate with rowmapper with parameters, using mockito only

Tags: junit, mockito

Hi i need help mocking the below statement.

```
List<String> testString= jdbcTemplate.query(queryString, new Object[] { someStringParameter }, new testMapper());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this working using the below mock
   `when(jdbcTemplateMock.query(anyString(), Matchers.<Object[]> anyVararg(),
                Matchers.any(testMapper.class)))`

Answer (score 5):

Mock `JdbcTemplate` method `query(String, Object[], RowMapper<T>)` using a RowMapper and ArgumentMatchers:

```
List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(someModel);

when(this.jdbcTemplate.query(anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.<Object[]>any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<RowMapper<Model>>any())).thenReturn(list);
```